# How can I make this execution plan more efficient?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2017, type-conversion

I have worked out all the implicit conversions, but I still see mentions of it in the plan. I have attached the plan, and any recommendation will help.

```
select cardholder_index, sum(value) as [RxCost] 
into #rxCosts 
from RiskPredictionStatistics with (nolock) where model_name = 'prescription_cost_12_months'
 and model_set_name = 'rx_updated' and run_id in (select value from #runIds) 
 and exists (select 1 from StringContainsHelper with (nolock) where IntValue = cardholder_index and ReferenceId = @stringContainsHelperRefId)
group by cardholder_index
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyHl9xFeS

Comment: It appears the bulk of the plan is spent on a Primary Key Lookup on `dbo.RiskPredictionStatistics`.  Would we be able to get the table schema and index information in your question? We will probably want details for how the `temporary table` `#runIDs` is built as well as the schema and index information for `StringContainsHelper`.  Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like when you populate the `#runIds` table -- and I'm just taking a wild guess here -- you're using a string splitter function that outputs the values as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

[image: NUTS]

You could try converting the values there to get rid of the implicit conversion warnings.

Another possible improvement would be to alter the `NonClustereIndex-Cardholder` index on RiskProductionStatistics to have `model_set_name` as a key column, and `model_name, run_id, value` as included columns. This would address the Key Lookup.

[image: NUTS]

[image: NUTS]

You may also want to check the datatype of `model_name`. It appears in a Filter operator, and my fear is that it's a MAX datatype, which may prevent the [predicate from being pushed down](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/max-data-types/).

[image: NUTS]

Since this is an estimated plan, and you haven't included any metrics about the query, it's hard to say how much improvement these changes will have.